# Symfony Oracle DB Connection Lost or network error - ORA-03113

Tags: oracle, symfony, debian, timeout, supervisord

After searching for days i hope that someone here can help me.

I've a dockerfile for php with nginx, oracle client and supervisord. This image is based on "php:7.4-fpm" and "oracle-instantclient19.5".

When i try to start a long running sql script (example: "BEGIN sys.DBMS_LOCK.sleep(600); END;") through a symfony command, then i'll get after ~300 seconds an ORA-03113 which points me to some kind of timeout or network error.

I've install sqlplus and have the same problem.

Things i've tried:

- php max_execution_time is set to 1800
- db admins cannot see a problem
- have searched for symfony timeouts and debian timeouts but could not find anything

Can someone point me to a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since this seems to be an irregular networking problem, I#ve decided to create an mView and refresh the data daily there. This works for now.